# Best way to bundle ~55MB of audio with app

Tags: android, audio

I have an app I am developing that needs to include about 55MB of audio (mp3s) these are short files and about 1000 in total. Bundling these in the apps assets makes the compiled apkabout 60MB.

I want to upload this app to the play store but of cause its to big as it it.
So my questions is, before I start working on using the APK Expansion File system is there anyway I could compress the audio files so the apk fits in under the 50MB limit?

The audios current bit rate is 128kbps

Comment: You should put these audio on server and when app launches you can download it to local filesystem if it is not already downloaded. Similar to 'Talking Tom' app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Its better if you can make a player for stream the audio from the internet just like youtube does for their android application to play video files on android phone.

Additionally you can give option to the user to select save the audio for next time play without internet download.

I think this is a good question and +1 from me